# what I do when I click on another div other than first div then css of first div will be disappear?

Tags: jquery

we use click function for first div that its css will display when i click on it what I do when I click on another div other than first div then css of first div will be disappear

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $('#Radio1').click(function(){
             $('.RadioBack').css({'background-color':'lightgray','min-height':'100px'});
         });
       });
```

But it only do that when I click on radio1 css of div RadioBack will display but when i click on div radio2 ,radio3,radio4 css of RadioBack will never disappear

Comment: Add HTML too please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not included any `html` so I'm using a simple red box, blue box.

Instead of specifying the css in jQuery, I would recommend adding your changes in the stylesheet then toggle a class name on the `div` you want to change the the colour of.

In this example, click on the red box to make it turn gray, then the blue box to turn it red again. Clicking on the gray box will not turn it red because of the `:not()` selector we are using to change the background colour.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //When click on this div, change background colour.
  $('#Radio1').click(function() {
    $('.RadioBack').addClass('lightgray');
  });
  
  //When click on any other div, change background colour back.
  $('div:not(#Radio1)').click(function() {
    $('.RadioBack').removeClass('lightgray');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div+div {
  background: blue;
}

div.lightgray {
      background-color:lightgray;
      min-height:100px'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Radio1" class="RadioBack"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help in very short time